# Magento 2 Youtube V3 Api Error: "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

A few months ago I created an API key for the Youtube V3 API so we could make use of product videos in magento 2. Now all of a sudden I get the following error:

```
Error: "Video cant be shown due to the following reason: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.
```

I checked the quota in de cloud console, and the total amount of requests made is 9. This indicates that we did not actually reach the quota, but I also don't know what else this could be. There is no indication in the cloud console that other API's reached their quota, or that something is wrong at all.

- Magento version: 2.3.3
- PHP version: 7.2

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you have 90 days of inactivity?

Comment: I just created an YouTube v3 api key also and having the same problem.  Did you figure this out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok its solved. The api was automatically disactivated by google due to inactivity. Simply add in your existing console.cloud.google.com a new project with youtube v3 api.